# Unable to start Windows Phone 8 SDK

Tags: windows-phone-8, virtual-machine, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator, windows-phone-8-sdk

I have installed Windows Phone 8 SDK with Visual Studio 2012 Professional with all updates. When I create a sample project and try to run its not showing any emulator to run on
[image]

When I am running the XDE file directly from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\8.0 path its showing me following errors:

[image]

then when I am hitting retry its shows me following error

[image]

After clean installation over and over again the SDK is not able to create a Virtual machine as shown below

[image]

What should I do now???

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute Visual Studio as Administrator

Answer (score 0):

As said above, try to execute VS 2012 as administrator and if that doesn't work, re-install VS 2012 and Phone SDK.